# How can i show UIProgressView while downloading/converting data from array of image url?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, uiprogressview

I have an array of URL. I am getting this URL from server and want to save that image URL data into my SQL data base so while converting  this image URL into data and then save that data into my data base,want to show Progress using UIProgressView.

Please let me know about this.

Comment: have you tried anything, any code?

Comment: I see lot of code but i can't understand how can i get the total number of bytes because to show the progress i need total number of bytes.

Comment: @rmaddy No,in that case they know the total number of bytes but in my case i can't

Comment: You can't show a progress view if you don't know the progress. And you can't know the progress unless you know the final size and the amount sent so far.

Comment: yes that is i know that's why i want to know is there any solution/way to achieve my task.

Comment: Is your question how to determine the final size or is your question how to show progress when you don't have enough info to so the progress?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51359/discussion-between-virantporwal-and-rmaddy)

Comment: I want both because i need both.

Comment: Get the size of data to be downloaded from the Content-Length http header (expectedContentLength) in the link from @rmaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

**ASIHTTPRequest** is the best option for that.

For Setup **ASIHTTPRequest** in your project please check this [link](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions)

After importing ASIHTTPRequest classes in your project import that two classes ASIHTTPRequest.h and ASINetworkQueue.h in your class then define  UIProgressView *proGress &
ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue object into your .h file.

now code for .m file is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //adata=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [[self networkQueue] cancelAllOperations];
    // Creating a new queue each time we use it means we don't have to worry about clearing delegates or resetting progress tracking
    [self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
    [[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];
    [[self networkQueue] setDownloadProgressDelegate:pgress];

    [[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [[self networkQueue] setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/tests/images/large-image.jpg"]];
        [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
    }
    [[self networkQueue] go];

}
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    //NSData *response = [request responseData];

    if ([[self networkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {

        [self setNetworkQueue:nil];
    }
    //... Handle success
    //[adata addObject:response];
    NSLog(@"Request finished =%f",[pgress progress]);
}


- (void)queueFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if ([[self networkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {
        [self setNetworkQueue:nil];
    }
    NSLog(@"Queue finished =%f",[pgress progress]);
    //img.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[adata objectAtIndex:0]];
}

- (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
      NSLog(@"error =%@",error);
}
```